# Export to csv in specified format

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv

After trying answers of almost every related question on SO,
I am still not getting it.

HTML File:

```
<li><a ng-click="exportToCsv('#total');">
<i class="fa fa-file-o mr-right7"></i>Export to CSV</a></li>
```

Controller File:

```
$scope.exportToCsv=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
          $scope.exportHref=Csv.tableToExcel(tableId,'List');
            $timeout(function(){location.href=$scope.exportHref;},100);
```

And my function in controller file itself.

```
gModule.factory('Csv',function($window){
        var uri='data:text/comma-separated-values;base64,',
            template='<table>{table}</table>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};

        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
});
```

***I need to export the data in the table in csv format but I am getting the whole html code instead.***

*I am supposed to make changed in this format only.*
Please Guide. Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally best **not to roll your own** when it comes to pre-existing formats. There are a lot of intricities which may not be immediately obvious with CSV files, like delimiters, escaping, nulls, the unicode BOM, and others. Use an existing library which has already dealt with all of the edge cases.

I'd recommend looking at [ng-csv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv) which will do what you need.